# Popup in qml : (closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose)

Tags: qt, popup, qml

When ever i am using closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose,
This popup is opened all the time and not getting closed (which is valid). When i am switching to some other screen, popup is opened and visible in other screens also.
How to avoid this kind of behaviour?

Note: I want popup to be visible specific to that particular screen where it is opened and not on other screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Binding` to control the popup's visibility based on the name of the screen it was opened in:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Popup {
        id: popup
        width: 200
        height: 200
        visible: true
        closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose

        property string originalScreenName

        Component.onCompleted: originalScreenName = ApplicationWindow.window.screen.name

        Binding {
            target: popup
            property: "visible"
            value: popup.ApplicationWindow.window.screen.name === popup.originalScreenName
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if the name property can change during the lifetime of the application (e.g. due to a user renaming it), but so far it's the only way I've found of uniquely identifying a screen, as the other properties like `serialNumber` are not set for me, and [QTBUG-85934](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85934) prevents comparing screen objects.